# Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+n+n^2)^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Tags: limits, binomial-theorem

> Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+n+n^2)^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Specifically how to apply the binomial theorem to the function that we are taking the limit of? My calculus professor says we need to make use of the binomial theorem.

Comment: Use latex please

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a variation on the standard proof that $n^{1/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. And you can see that the usual binomial theorem for positive integral index is used here in a crucial manner.

---

You can observe that $1 + n + n^{2} > 1$ and hence $(1 + n + n^{2})^{1/n} > 1$ and therefore if we set $(1 + n + n^{2})^{1/n} = 1 + x_{n}$ then $x_{n} > 0$. So we have $$1 + n + n^{2} = (1 + x_{n})^{n} = \sum_{r = 0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}x_{n}^{r}$$ Since $x_{n} > 0$ it is obvious that if we just take any specific term in the binomial expansion on RHS then this single term is less than the whole binomial sum and hence less than $1 + n + n^{2}$. Taking the term corresponding to $r = 3$ we get $$\binom{n}{3}x_{n}^{3} < 1 + n + n^{2}$$ for all $n \geq 3$ or $$0 < x_{n}^{3} < \frac{6(1 + n + n^{2})}{n(n - 1)(n - 2)}$$ and by Squeeze Theorem we get $$\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n}^{3} = 0$$ and using continuity of $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ we see that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n} = 0$$ and hence $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + n + n^{2})^{1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + x_{n}) = 1$$

Answer (score 3):

**hint:** $1 < 1+\dfrac{1}{n} + \dfrac{1}{n^2} < 3$

Comment: Your hint implies that n^(2/n) < (1+n+n^2)^(1/n) < 3^(1/n) n^(2/n), is this correct?

Comment: $3^{1/n} \to 1$ and $n^{2/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Then I take n ---> infinity and use Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: and then I get 1 < (1+n+n^2)^(1/n) < 1, so by Squeeze Theorem limit is 1

Answer (score 2):

Consider $$A_n= (1+n+n^2)^{\frac{1}{n}}\implies \log(A_n)=\frac 1n \log(1+n+n^2)=\frac 1n \left(\log(n^2)+\log(1+\frac 1 n+\frac 1 {n^2})\right)$$ Now, using for small values of $x$ $$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ replace $x$ by $\frac 1 n+\frac 1 {n^2}$ (here will appear the binomial expansion).

This gives $$\log(1+\frac 1 n+\frac 1 {n^2})=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ So $$\log(A_n)=\frac 1n \left(2\log(n)+ \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)=2\frac{\log(n)}{n}+\frac 1 {n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: More simply, $1+\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}\to1$ (obvious) hence $\log\left(1+\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}\right)\to0$ (continuity of the function logarithm at $1$) and $\log(n)\to\infty$ (obvious) hence $\log A_n\sim2\frac{\log n}{n}\to0$, qed. Jumping on expansions is not always necessary...

Comment: @Did. Could I do anything except agreeing 100% with you ?

Comment: I went as far as posting the preceding message because I have read many answers where you seem to automatically Taylor-expand everything to order 3 or 4 when order 0 or 1 would be enough and where Taylor-expanding in itself is actually not useful at all. But understand that we are here at the level of getting *better* answers, not only technically correct answers...

Comment: @Did. The OP wrote *My calculus professor says we need to make use of the binomial theorem*. This is why I made this answer which, I agree, is overkilling. In French, we use to say :"taking a big hammer for killing a small fly".

Comment: This seems to be another topic -- but you lost me: where do you use the binomial theorem? Or do you show how not to?

Answer (score 1):

The binomial theorem seems to me less important than this well-known limit:

$n^{\frac{1}{n}}\rightarrow 1$

Do you see how to proceed from here?

Comment: If you cannot, think of the best way in which to bound $(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2})^{\frac{1}{n}}$ from above and below.

Comment: By the way, how do you show that n^(1/n) ---> 1?

Comment: @user362922 $n^\frac1n = e^{\frac1n\ln n}\to e^0.$